# instanceof JSONObject doesn't detect JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I found strange behaviour of `variable instanceof JSONObject`. I have following code:

```
Object value;
try {
    value = customer.get(key);
    Log.v("type", String.valueOf(value.getClass())); // Returns JSONObject
    if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
        // Handle JSONObject
    } else {
        String text = (String)value;  // HERE COMES THE ERROR
        // Handle String
    }
```

When log returns JSONObject it ends up with exception:

```
01-15 12:24:46.206 4111-4111/cz.jacon.goldympos V/CUSTOMER type: class org.json.JSONObject$1
01-15 12:24:46.207 4111-4111/cz.jacon.goldympos D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-15 12:24:46.279 4111-4111/cz.jacon.goldympos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                   Process: cz.jacon.goldympos, PID: 4111
                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cz.jacon.goldympos/cz.jacon.goldympos.activities.CustomerDetailActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                            at cz.jacon.goldympos.activities.CustomerDetailActivity.getText(CustomerDetailActivity.java:260)
                            at cz.jacon.goldympos.activities.CustomerDetailActivity.createLayout(CustomerDetailActivity.java:222)
                            at cz.jacon.goldympos.activities.CustomerDetailActivity.onCreate(CustomerDetailActivity.java:92)
                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                        ...........
```

Am I missing something? It looks so simple...

EDIT: json

Example of json I using. First is JSONObject, second is Integer (can be casted to String)

```
{
"viewers_edit_time":
    {
     "date":"2016-01-14 22:53:56.000000",
     "timezone_type":3,
     "timezone":"Asia/Kolkata"
    },
"viewers_edit_users_id":1
}
```

[That's full json](http://pastebin.com/cgUxAkwS), exactly the same I'm using. And again:

```
Log.v("type", String.valueOf(value.getClass())); // Returns JSONObject not JSONObject$1
```

---

**SOLVED**

Problem solved. From the full JSON I've posted in question:

```
"viewers_postcode": null
```

I didn't noticed that null isn't in quotation marks... Before I was thinking that i was "null" which is String. I was mistaken by error message I got, which says `JSONObject$1 cannot be casted to String`. But JSONObject`$1` is NULL (credits to @Natix)

Maybe it helps to other people with the same error message.

Comment: I think `Object` can not be instance of `JSONObject` as `Object` is super. Condition will always be false.

Comment: Post Json & Code so able to give correct answer .

Comment: Are you sure error is coming at that line? I don't find anything wrong here.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 see the edit. The error comes from line when I try to cast JSONObject to String... because of wrong if statement

Comment: Can you see if you have imported class `org.json.JSONObject` or from some other package?

Comment: @MustansarSaeed Guess if it was true, Rohit5k2's answer would work

Comment: @Rohit5k2 yes, that was the first thing I checked before posting this question. And no other class with name JSONObject is not imported

Comment: what is `customer` and what returns `customer.get(key)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pay careful attention to the log message. The point is that `org.json.JSONObject$1` is **not** the same as class `org.json.JSONObject`.

The `$1`suffix means it's an anonymous inner class of the JSONObject class. If you look in [the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-6.0.1_r5/json/src/main/java/org/json/JSONObject.java), you'll find this bit of code:

```
public static final Object NULL = new Object() {
    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o == this || o == null; // API specifies this broken equals implementation
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "null";
    }
};
```

This means that you should first check if your value is equal to this NULL constant:

```
Object value = customer.get(key);
if (value == JSONObject.NULL {
    // Handle NULL
} else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
    // Handle JSONObject
} else {
    // Handle String
}
```

Comment: Ok, that works, but does it mean that value is NULL?

Comment: @Natix: NULL is the inner class of `JSONObject ` , i think there should be a proper way. it looks like that `customer.get(Key)` is not returing the `jsonObject`

Comment: @kikinet It's not null in the Java sense, it's null in the context of JSON. The docs say: _A sentinel value used to explicitly define a name with no value. Unlike null, names with this value: show up in the names() array, show up in the keys() iterator, return true for has(String), do not throw on get(String), are included in the encoded JSON string._

Comment: @MustansarSaeed `String.valueOf(cutomer.get(key).getClass())` returns `JSONObject`. You can see it in example in my question. It's copied from browser, not written by hand. `viewers_edit_type` returns `JSONObject`

Comment: @MustansarSaeed `JSONObject.NULL` in an instance of an anonymous inner class of `JSONObject`, but is doesn't extend it, it extends `java.lang.Object`. The proper way is calling `customer.isNull(key)`, but that basically just compares it against the NULL constant as in the answer above.

Comment: @Natix the thing is, its a hacky method, is `customer.get(key)` returns `JSONObject` then condition should work

Comment: Ok, so I cannot cast it to JSONObject. How can I get value from it? For example: `customer.get(key).getString(String)` is underlined and says: Cannot resolve method getString(java.lang.String). When I cast it to JSONObject it returns runtime `JSONObject$1 cannot be cast to JSONObject`

Comment: @MustansarSaeed No, it does NOT return `JSONObject`. It returns `JSONObject$1`, which is NOT the same thing. I don't see anything hacky in here.

Comment: @kikinet Please put the first condition as `object instanceof String` and see what happens. It looks like that `customer.get(key)` is returing `String` instead of `JSONObject`

Comment: @kikinet _How can I get value from it?_ You can't. It it's NULL, then it means, there isn't any value. :) If you expect a value to be there, you should check your input data.